# Reading your own filename through android-ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to read my own filename/path (i.e.my own apk path) through native code(ndk).
Is it possible to read ?

Thanks ,
Chetan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get your own .apk path in Java code, and then pass it to your native code. It's unlikely you can achieve same result with just 1 (one!) line of native code:

```
String my_apk_path = context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir;
```